# How to get Hyperledger fabric block timestamp?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm using hyperledger fabric node sdk.
I got some block informations by EventHub API and Channel API, but those informations had no block timestamp.

[hyperledger/blockchain-explorer](https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer)
It seems like the block timestamp doesn't exist on this blockchain explorer too.
Isn't there block timestamp of hyperledger fabric?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A timestamp is not included in the block header as of the 1.0 release but it may be added in a future release.  A workaround is to use the timestamp from one of the transactions in the block instead.